# Javascript for zooming and panning an image

Tags: javascript, html

I have a requirement in the project I am working on for a piece of JavaScript which will allow the user to pan over and zoom in and out of a large image.

Unfortunately, my experience with JavaScript is limited.

Does anybody know of a free script out there which would satisfy my requirements?

Answer (score 5):

There is a jquery ZoomImage plug-in to my opinion which would be good use for this case..Examples for code are [here](http://www.eyecon.ro/zoomimage/) or [here](http://www.suuronen.org/esa-matti/projects/panfullsize/).

There is one that also uses a zoom toolbar next to the [image](http://www.oneblackbear.com/zoom/index.html)